# Python: 1d kmeans cluster data point count label

Tags: python, plot, count, label, k-means

I've followed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113595/how-to-get-k-means-cluster-for-1d-data) and  successfully created plot and analysis.

My question: is there a way to add a label that shows count of values in each of the clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get the clusters sizes using pandas
then put the text on the plot using matplotlib

```
cluster_sizes = df.groupby('label').size().reset_index(name='size')

cluster_size_0 = cluster_sizes[cluster_sizes['label'] == 0]['size'].item()
cluster_size_1 = cluster_sizes[cluster_sizes['label'] == 1]['size'].item()

cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_.ravel()

plt.text(cluster_centers[0], 0.4, cluster_size_0, fontsize=12)
plt.text(cluster_centers[1], 0.4, cluster_size_1, fontsize=12)
```

Comment: `plt.text` returns `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @vbadvd I made a mistake, check updated answer